# Сравнение даты в шаблоне

Tags: python, django

Всем привет

Как правильно сравнить дату в шаблоне с текущей? Пробовал так:

```
                {% if message.Time|date != now|date %}
                    {{message.Time|date:"d.m.y"}}
                {% endif %}
```

Ошибок не выдает, но для любых дат в message.Time, в т.ч. и текущей, `message.Time|date != now|date` возвращает true.

Если сравнивать в таком духе:

```
{% if message.Time|date"d.m.y" != now|date"d.m.y" %}
```

то получаю

> Could not parse the remainder: '"d.m.y"' from
>   'message.Time|date"d.m.y"'

Comment: А без фильтров пробовали сравнивать?

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров, не пробовал, т.к. мне нужно сравнить дату, а без фильтров будет время

Comment: В документации, чтобы получить из now дату применяется не фильтр, а просто в тег передается параметр с нужным форматом: `{% now "Y" as current_year %}` (сохранить год в переменную current_year)
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/ - найдите тут now

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров, да. Так получилось. Спасибо